# How to set content type for emails sent using spring's JavaMailSenderImpl

Tags: spring, email, jakarta-mail, velocity

question is from subject. I'm using JavaMailSenderImpl from spring 3.0.3.RELEASE and velocity 1.6.4 for mail preparation from template.

When I send email with Croatian characters from my webapp  recipient  receives "?" in stand of normal Croatian characters. If I turn debug mode for mails,
 from log I can see that **Content-type** is set to:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

How can I set it to:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8?
```

I'm using gmail for mail sending while I'm developing this webapp.

Here are my settings in spring's servlet xml conf file:

```
<bean id="userAuthorizationManager" class="com.mypackage.manage.SimpleUserAuthorizationManagerImpl">
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
    <property name="velocityEngine" ref="velocityEngine" />
    <property name="from" value="address" />
    <property name="authorizationAddress" value="some text" />
    <property name="subject" value="some text" />
</bean>

<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="465" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="pass" />
    <property name="protocol" value="smtps" />

    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.connectiontimeout">5000</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.sendpartial">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.userset">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.mime.charset">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.isSecure">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.requiresAuthentication">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.port">465</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="velocityEngine"
        class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="velocityProperties">
        <value>
            resource.loader=class
                class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here is my code from mail manager:

```
private void sendConfirmationEmail(final User user, final int requestId) {
        MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
                MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
                message.setTo(user.getEmailAddress());
                message.setFrom(from);
                message.setSubject(subject);

                Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                model.put("user", user);
                model.put("authorizationAddress", authorizationAddress);
                model.put("requestId", requestId);
                String text = VelocityEngineUtils
                        .mergeTemplateIntoString(
                                velocityEngine,
                                "com/mypackage/mail/registration-confirmation.vm",
                                model);
                message.setText(text, true);
            }
        };
        PendingMail pendingMail = new PendingMail(preparator);
        pool.submit(pendingMail);

    }
private class PendingMail implements Callable<Object> {
                MimeMessagePreparator preparator;

        protected PendingMail(MimeMessagePreparator preparator) {
            this.preparator = preparator;
        }

        public Object call() {
            mailSender.send(preparator);
            return null;
            }
}
```

Have you any other suggestion?

Regards,
Tiho

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I resolved my problem thanks to
[this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20111201230422/http://www.toolsforteams.com:80/roller/blog/entry/gmail_via_spring_javamailsenderimpl).

According to the post I put this in the mailSender bean configuration:

```
<property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
```

Comment: I was going nuts with this one for romanian characters sent as html. Thank You!

Comment: Here ist the post at archive.org: [GMail via Spring JavaMailSenderImpl](https://web.archive.org/web/20101001041008/http://www.toolsforteams.com/roller/blog/entry/gmail_via_spring_javamailsenderimpl)

Comment: @ma cılay Thanks for new link, I'll ad it to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can set this as a property `mail.mime.charset` in the JavaMailSenderImpl spring bean config. See an example answered at this [previous query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541846/spring-javamailsenderimpl-where-to-set-the-charset/547207#547207).

Comment: Hi,
thanks for your answer, but I have already set this property as you can see in next post.

Comment: It doesn't wokr in my case, I want to display polish characters correctly:( I tried each solution...

Answer (score 1):

2020 answer, as XML configuration is not very used now:

```
JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
mailSender.getJavaMailProperties().put("mail.mime.charset", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be:

```
JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
mailSender.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
```